# Проблема с работой функции strcmpi() в си

Tags: c, функции

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с работой функции strcmpi(). Вот код:

```
fscanf(inp, "%d\n", &nalog);
for (n = 1; n <= nalog; n++)
{

    fscanf(inp, "%s %s\n", &INP1, &INP2);
    nal = atoi(INP2);
    sravn = strcmpi(INP1, OBJ1);
    if (sravn == 0)
    {
        k++;
    }
    printf("%d", k);
```

Предоставляю комментарий ошибки:
    'strcmpi': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strcmpi. See online help for details.
Хотелось бы узнать как решить данную проблему. Функцию  strcmpi() использовать необходимо, т.к по заданию нужно сравнить строки независимо от регистра символов. Заранее спасибо

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1964821/4928642

Comment: См. [man strcasecmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp)

Answer (score 0):

Ну написано же:

> Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strcmpi.

Замени `strcmpi` на `_strcmpi`.

Comment: Ок, ошибка исчезла. Но результат не тот. Я правильно понимаю, что если при выполнении моего кода sravn будет равен 0, то это означает что строки одинаковы?